# how to replace missing values from another column in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, coalesce

I want to use values in t5 to replace some missing values in t4. Searched code, but doesn’t work for me

- Current:
  [example of current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Y96.png)
- Goal:

[example of target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQGyb.png)

df is a dataframe.Code:

```
pdf = df.toPandas()  

from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce
pdf.withColumn("t4", coalesce(pdf.t4, pdf.t5))
```

   Error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'withColumn'

Also, tried the following code previously, didnt work neither.

```
new_pdf=pdf['t4'].fillna(method='bfill', axis="columns")
```

Error: No axis named columns for object type

Comment: Looks like pdf is a pandas dataframe, not a spark dataframe

Comment: Please show us a few rows of your dataframe and how this rows should look after applying your logic. Is there a reason why you have converted it to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Thank you all. Added images, not sure if you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error indicates **.withColumn()** is not a method of pandas dataframes but spark dataframes. Note that when using **.toPandas()**  your pdf becomes a pandas dataframe, so if you want to use  **.withColumn()** avoid the transformation

**UPDATE:**
If pdf is a pandas dataframe you can do:

```
pdf['t4']=pdf['t4'].fillna(pdf['t5'])
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try using Pandas first. But it didnt work. Do you know the reasons too?  CODE: new_pdf=pdf['t4'].fillna(method='ffill', axis="columns")    ERROR: No axis named columns for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: If pdf is a pandas dataframe you can do: `pdf['t4']=pdf['t4'].fillna(pdf['t5'])`